# Current players in a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there a way to see the current players in a server from the client program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can type `/list` to see a list of all connected players

Note however, that if a server is running mods, the usual command is `/playerlist`

Also, you can use `/help` to get more information about the commands.

Do note that you need to be op to run `/list`, and mods might disable or restrict the `/playerlist` commands for certain users or usergroups.